# Getting error on Text() - A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the completed project from this repository(https://github.com/londonappbrewery/destini-challenge-completed)

I am getting error on Text() widget and in follow calls.

```
storyBrain.getStory();
storyBrain.getChoice1();
storyBrain.getChoice2();
```

error:

```
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 285 pos 10: 'data != null'
```

[image]

**WorkAround** -
I tried converting it to string using `.toString()` but still getting same error.

**Flutter Doctor**-

```
E:\Temp\flutter\destini-challenge-starting>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
> Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.778], locale en-IN)

> Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
> Android Studio (version 3.6)
> VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.44.2)
> Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Check the text widget that you are using, you are passing null value to text widget.. It will through an error

Answer (score 1):

it's because your object didn't got initialized yet, and to solve that we need more code but to save yourself from null exception use `??` like this it will check if what's before it is null then it will display the value after `??`.

```
storyBrain.getStory() ?? 'default value';
storyBrain.getChoice1() ?? 'default value';
storyBrain.getChoice2() ?? 'default value';
```